# How to search for text in the Access Class Objects in an accdb file

Tags: vba, ms-access, search

My team has many Access database files that use VB in their form classes to call stored procedures.

I want to be able to search the Access Class Objects in these accdb files for the stored procedure names, but Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications doesn't seem to support searching all the class definitions at once.

Is there a way to search all the Access Class Objects in a accdb file for a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA solution didn't print the CodeBehindForm section for me, but I did get success using the Interop libraries.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
using System;

namespace AccessExporter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();

            String fileName = @"C:\AccessFile.accdb";
            app.Visible = false;
            app.OpenCurrentDatabase(fileName);

            foreach (AccessObject obj in app.CurrentProject.AllForms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
                app.SaveAsText(AcObjectType.acForm, obj.Name, String.Format(@"C:\{0}.txt", obj.Name));
            }

            app.CloseCurrentDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the hidden `Application.SaveAsText` VBA method to dump the forms to text files and then use your favorite searching tool (something like [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html), perhaps) to rummage through the files looking for those SP names. The code to dump the forms would be something like this:

```
Sub DumpFormsToText()
Dim frm As Variant
Const OutFolder = "C:\__tmp\FormDump\"
For Each frm In Application.CurrentProject.AllForms
    Application.SaveAsText acForm, frm.Name, OutFolder & frm.Name & ".txt"
Next
Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That was very helpful, but the output of passing a form to SaveAsText doesn't include the Event Procedure definition in the form's command buttons. Is there any way to print that out too?

Comment: @user467384 Sorry, I don't understand: The `Begin CommandButton` block that contains the `Name =` attribute also contains the `OnClick ="[Event Procedure]"` attribute, and the actual VBA code is in the `CodeBehindForm` section at the bottom of the file. What's missing?

Comment: My output text files don't have the CodeBehindForm section anywhere in any of the files I've generated.

Comment: I can export the Access Class Objects to text by right clicking on them and selecting "Export" in MS Visual Basic for Applications, but I can't Export multiple files at a time that way.